# Cross-multiplying table

Tags: sql

I have this SQL code and I want to show the sum of each item on its charge slip and on their receipt:

```
select item_description, sum(receipt_qty) as Samp1, sum(chargeSlip_qty) as Samp2
from Items inner join Receipt_Detail on (Receipt_Detail.item_number =
    Items.item_number)
inner join ChargeSlip_Detail on (ChargeSlip_Detail.item_number =
    Items.item_number)
group by item_description
```

It produces this output:

```
Acetazolamide 2681 1730
Ascorbic Acid 1512 651
Paracetamol   1370 742
Silk          576  952
```

But it should be:

```
Acetazolamide 383  173
Ascorbic Acid 216  93
Paracetamol   274  106
Silk          96   238
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are joining tables, you might have a one-to-many relationship that is causing the problem when you then get the `sum()`.  So you can use subqueries to get the result. This will get the `sum()` for the `receipt` and `chargeslip` for each `item_number` and then you join that back to your `items` table to get the final result:

```
select i.item_description, 
  r.Samp1, 
  c.Samp2
from Items i
inner join
(
  select sum(receipt_qty) Samp1,
    item_number
  from Receipt_Detail 
  group by item_number
) r
  on r.item_number = i.item_number
inner join
(
  select sum(chargeSlip_qty) Samp2,
    item_number
  from ChargeSlip_Detail 
  group by item_number
) c 
  on c.item_number = i.item_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the GROUP BYs first, per `Item_Number`, so you don't multiply out rows from `Receipt_Detail` and `ChargeSlip_Detail`. That is, you generate the SUM values per `Item_Number` before JOINing back to `Items`

```
select
    I.item_description,
    R.Samp1,
    C.Samp2
from
    Items I
    inner join
    (SELECT item_number, sum(receipt_qty) as Samp1
      FROM Receipt_Detail
      GROUP BY item_number
    ) R
        on (R.item_number = I.item_number)
    inner join
    (SELECT item_number, sum(chargeSlip_qty) as Samp2
      FROM ChargeSlip_Detail
      GROUP BY item_number
    ) C
        on (C.item_number = I.item_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

A left join returns rows from the left table, and for each row in the left table, all matching rows in the right table.

So for example:

```
create table Customers (name varchar(50));
insert Customers values 
    ('Tim'), 
    ('John'), 
    ('Spike');
create table Orders (customer_name varchar(50), product varchar(50));
insert Orders values (
    ('Tim', 'Guitar'), 
    ('John', 'Drums'), 
    ('John', 'Trumpet');
create table Addresses (customer_name varchar(50), address varchar(50));
insert Addresses values (
    ('Tim', 'Penny Lane 1'), 
    ('John', 'Abbey Road 1'), 
    ('John', 'Abbey Road 2');
```

Then if you run:

```
select  c.name
,       count(o.product) as Products
,       count(a.address) as Addresses
from Customers c
left join Orders o on o.customer_name = c.name
left join Addresses a on a.customer_name = c.name
group by name
```

You get:

```
name    Products    Addresses
Tim     1           1
John    4           4
Spike   0           0
```

But John doesn't have 4 products!
If you run without the `group by`, you can see why the counts are off:

```
select  *
from Customers c
left join Orders o on o.customer_name = c.name
left join Addresses a on a.customer_name = c.name
```

You get:

```
name    customer_name   product     customer_name   address
Tim     Tim             Guitar      Tim             Penny Lane 1
John    John            Drums       John            Abbey Road 1
John    John            Drums       John            Abbey Road 2
John    John            Trumpet     John            Abbey Road 1
John    John            Trumpet     John            Abbey Road 2
Spike   NULL            NULL        NULL            NULL
```

As you can see, the joins end up repeating each other.  For each product, the list of addresses is repeated.  That gives you the wrong counts.  To solve this problem, use one of the excellent other answers:

```
select  c.name
,       o.order_count
,       a.address_count
from    Customers c
left join 
        (
        select  customer_name
        ,       count(*) as order_count
        from    Orders 
        group by
                customer_name          
        ) o
on      o.customer_name = c.name
left join 
        (
        select  customer_name
        ,       count(*) as address_count
        from    Addresses 
        group by
                customer_name          
        ) a
on      a.customer_name = c.name
```

The subqueries ensure only one row is joined per customer.  The result is much better:

```
name    order_count address_count
Tim     1           1
John    2           2
Spike   NULL        NULL
```